# WCF Named Pipes: Streaming (Configuration) issue

Tags: wcf, streaming, named-pipes, netnamedpipebinding

I'm building a WCF services to transfer large files (~8 Gig) between two processes by using named pipes.

I've got the concept working to transfer small files in streaming mode. Although for larger files i have to increase the maxReceivedMessageSize. I can specifiy the bindingConfiguration in the host app.config without any problem.

The problem occurs when I specifiy the bindingConfiguration in the client endpoint in the client app.config.

```
bindingConfiguration="MyNamedPipeBinding"
```

The error message i get:

> The .Net Framing mode being used is not supported by
>   'net.pipe://localhost/MyService'. See the server logs for more
>   details.
>
> Framing mode Singleton is not supported.

**Host config:**

```
<services>
  <service name="MyService">
    <endpoint
      address="net.pipe://localhost/MyService"
      binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="MyNamedPipeBinding"
      contract="MyApp.MyService"
      name="MyServiceEndpoint"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="MyNamedPipeBinding" 
             transferMode="StreamedResponse" 
             maxBufferSize="32768" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="21474836480">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Client config:**

```
<client>
  <endpoint
    address="net.pipe://localhost/MyService"
    binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="MyNamedPipeBinding"
    contract="MyApp.MyService"
    name="MyServiceEndpoint">
  </endpoint>
</client>
<bindings>
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="MyNamedPipeBinding" 
             transferMode="StreamedResponse" 
             maxBufferSize="32768" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="21474836480">
      <security mode="None"  />
    </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: OK, may be a n00b question here, but doesn't StreamedResponse allow communication in only one direction? If that's what you want, then shouldn't one of those be StreamedRequest? OTOH, if you want bi-directional comm, shouldn't you be using Streamed for both?

Comment: Did you check if the solution from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490627/net-tcp-binding-with-streamed-transfer-mode-framing-mode-singleton-is-not-supp) works for you?